# Parsing text in Chrome/Firefox extension to choose which URL to send the highlighted text to

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a novice programmer, and I am struggling with where to begin approaching this problem. I have created a simple Chrome extension where you can highlight a certain text and right click then send that text to a specific internal url + selection text like so:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(item, tab) {
let url =
'https://internalURL/prod/example/' + item.selectionText;
chrome.tabs.create({url: url, index: tab.index + 1});
});
```

The highlighted text is an internal identifier that is 11 characters long for our production environment and 9 for the lower environments. I want my extension to be smart enough to be able tell when a lower environment identifier is being highlighted and send that to a different URL than when 11 character strings are sent. Can anyone point me in the right direction or help show me how to accomplish this with javascript? I have tried googling to see if anyone else has tried to do something similar but I can't seem to find anything but I may just be searching the wrong terms.

Comment: Check item.selectionText.length

Comment: so would I be able to add two if statements where if item.selectionText.length = 9 then send to lower environment url and item.selectionText.length = 11 then send to production url?